# How do I save an ArrayList to the application settings

Tags: c#

I would like to save a arraylist to the settings class...does any one have an example I could follow.

c#, .net 2.0

Comment: (as an aside, the serializer will probably prefer a typed list...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Settings file editor, add a new setting that is of type System.Collections.Arraylist.

In your code, you can then set this value by doing:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting = myArrayList;
```